# Metaphor of collecting dirt

Tags: metaphor, sports

In episode 24 of the Japanese anime **Shin Atashin'chi**, around 13:45, a boy on the verge of tears collects a heap of dirt or sand with his hand while holding a sack in the other. This happens in reaction to hearing that his secret love interest finds an older boy attractive.

[image: scene from anime]

I assume this is a metaphor for somebody in despair or with their hopes shattered.

Is this interpretation correct?

Is the act a reference to a Japanese fairy tale, story, myth or legend?

Or is he digging his own grave because he is preparing for death from sadness?

*The episode is focused on the sport of Baseball. I mention this after reading the answer.*

Comment: [it´s a tradition that the lost team always take some sand away home as a good memory, and usually some cry…](http://www.iromegane.com/japan/culture/japanese-summer-event-koushien-koukou-yakyu/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [We don't do purely cultural questions](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/801/542). The questions need to relate to the language, since that is the focus of the site.

Comment: I wasn't asking about culture but about storytelling. The answer revealed that the storytelling element in question is based on Japanese Baseball culture.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The All-Japan Senior High School Baseball Championship Tournament is held at 甲子園 stadium every year.

There is a custom that losing teams bring a little dirt from 甲子園 stadium back to their school in memory. So, I think his action in this case means the thing you assumed.

Comment: Consuetude is such a beautiful word but I think 'custom' is more usual. (The two words are cognates anyway...)